# Woocommerce variable subscription

Tags: ecommerce, payments, subscription, woocommerce

I want to create a WooCommerce subscription, which is $5 /user /month.

I can create a subscription for **1** user/month, but I can't work out how to let people choose **x** users/month.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the actual WooCommerce Subscription Extension found here: http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/